# Is it possible to send woocommerce product url/price with contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a tour site with woocommerce where in product page a button is set called "Availability Check". After clicking this button a popup form (contact7) will show with few fields " Name, email and others" and submit button

I can do this with  contact form7 but problem is client want to receive product price and url with the same email. Is it possible to integrate with contact form7 if yes then how?

Or another solution there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following.

1. You may find a tab named CONTACT on the left side of our Wordpress admin dashboard.
2. Click on CONTACT to see the list of available forms.
3. Choose the form you want to edit and click EDIT.
4. On the right hand side column of edit page you will find a drop down menu called GENERATE TAG.
5. You will find options for url and text box there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the solution what i am looking for. I got a solution with the plugin "Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension". Successfully i received the product url now i am working on price.

Comment: Please explain about what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: I want to pass product url which will not submitted by user. It will automatically collect when contact form is submitted. I think contact form 7 default url tag is used to put the url from front end and check the url format is valid or not. I want to receive woo-commerce product details (URL, Price, Name). User just fill their name and email from product page.